# Deploy production build of ReactJS with Node express as backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, deployment, create-react-app

Hi even after lot of search i am still confused what is correct way to deploy my react app created using `create-react-app` with express as backend.
I ran `npm run build` which created build folder. I copied the build folder to be served as static folder of express and had put
`app.use(express.static('build'));`.
It is working fine for homepage, that is homepage opens when i run my express node server but when i go to anyother link outside homepage it gives `404`.
Everything is working fine in developer mode, which i run by `npm start` command. I just want to know what i am doing wrond here. Let me know anymore info required to understand the problem. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have the backend server running. You need to npm start your server, and then npm start your front end if that make sense. They are 2 separate things.

Comment: No, i am serving build folder as static folder in backend and i am running the backend server. And it opens homepage well but any link outside homepage is giving 404, though it worked well in development mode.. hope you get it.

Comment: What's giving 404s? Are they routes from the express app or are they static files as well?

Comment: the routes.. static files are working fine.

Comment: Did you try going to any GET route from your browser? It sounds like your express app is not running

Comment: No express app is running ow how would it serve the static folder. ! yes i am trying to GET route from browser, and homepage is getting rendered as well.. but links outside homepage aren't working

Comment: Again-- the front end is different from the backend. Your front end is running and that is how you're getting the home page. If you can not get to a GET route from the browser, that means your express app is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using client-side routing? A popular implementation of that is `react-router`.

Let say you are trying to access `/page1`, what client-side routing does is use the JS to toggle between different components to "fake" the routing, instead of rending a new HTML.

Yet, by default when you change routes, the browser does the usual stuff and send a GET request to the server asking for the corresponding HTML file. But since you only have `index.html` served, that's why you received 404.

You need to add the following at the end of your `app.js`, right before you call `app.listen` of your `express` server to tell the server to always return `index.html` no matter what route does it received.

```js
/* client-side routing. 
 * For GET requests from any routes (other than those which is specified above),
 * send the file "index.html" to the client-side from the folder "build"
 */
app.get("*", (_, res) => res.sendFile("index.html", { root: "build" }));

// your usual app.listen
app.listen(port, () => console.log("Listening"));
```